# Zalando's pages higher than 429 - How is it made?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I was trying to understand how Zalando's site works to scrape it and found something interesting and I really can't find an answer to this.

This link opens 2nd page of catalog 
https://www.zalando.co.uk/catalog/?p=2

So this link should open 800 page od catalog but it redirects to 429 page of catalog
https://www.zalando.co.uk/catalog/?p=800

It keeps redirecting to 429 page from pag 430,
 I mean
https://www.zalando.co.uk/catalog/?p=430 redirects to page 429

I can move to page 430 by clicking next button, but clicking href in this button dev tools also redirects to page 429. 
How to bypass it? How to create it? Why is it happening? I really want to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call directly an url `https://www.zalando.co.uk/catalog/?p=430` with param `p` highter than 429, the server send you back a [302 HTTP code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), which is common way of performing URL redirection.

Inside the response header, you can find the attribute `location` filled with `/catalog/?p=429`, so your client send you back to the page 429

To avoid this, you can use [selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html) and click on next page from the page 429

Comment: The other possibility to deal with such ways is to choose some categories and then search over pages.